# variable number of digit in format string

Tags: python

Which is a clean way to write this formatting function:

```
def percent(value,digits=0):
    return ('{0:.%d%%}' % digits).format(value)

>>> percent(0.1565)
'16%'

>>> percent(0.1565,2)
'15.65%'
```

the problem is formatting a number with a given number of digits, I don't like to use both '%' operator and format method.

Comment: You just don't like it? Looks fine to me?

Comment: @Aesthete: No. I don't like it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I like this one:

```
'{0:.{1}%}'.format(value, digits)
```

Test:

```
>> '{0:.{1}%}'.format(0.1565, 0)
'16%'
>> '{0:.{1}%}'.format(0.1565, 2)
'15.65%'
```

Comment: +1 - How is that described ? looking briefly @[format-spec](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) I don't see that it's valid to have nested formatspecs yet it undoubtedly works.

Comment: @sotapme - search for the word "nested" on your linked page.

Comment: I got a value error when digits was a str and not an int :+1: (so be sure your digits are numeric)

Comment: This is especially clean as you can now format multiple values with the same precision, mentioning it only once: `'{0:.{2}%}, {1:.{2}%}'.format(0.1565, 0.1234, 1)` yields: `'15.7%, 12.3%'`.

Answer (score 3):

[`*` does what you want](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), for `printf`-style string formatting.

```
>>> def percent(value, digits=0):
...     return '%.*f%%' % (digits, value * 100)
...
>>> percent(0.1565, 2)
'15.65%'
```

Advanced string formatting (defined in [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) and documented in [7.1.3. Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)) doesn't seem to be capable of doing this in one pass. (See [7.1.3.1. Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language): `precision` is `integer` only.)

Comment: Well, it is capable of doing this in one pass. See my answer.

Comment: precision refers to the number of digits. of course _it_ is an integer, but it can be _applied_ to floats

Comment: @gnibbler: I was referring to the grammar: `precision ::= integer`

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

> Minimum field width (optional). If specified as an '*' (asterisk), the
>   actual width is read from the next element of the tuple in values, and
>   the object to convert comes after the minimum field width and optional
>   precision.

Example:

```
def percent(value, digits=0):
    print '%.*f%%' % (digits, value*100)
>>> percent(0.1565, 2)
15.65%
```